# bash scripting: how to sort a string in the form of "number.text number.text etc" in ascending order?

Tags: string, bash, sorting, scripting

for example if we have in a variable named "var"

a string "2.test 1.test 9.test"

i want it to be

1.test 2.test 9.test

I was trying to apply this command

```
    echo $var | sort -n
```

but the output isn't correct because if for example I have

2.text
11.text

it will print

11.text 2.text which is wrong because 11>2

thanks

Comment: Should work, it works for me. Have you tried to reverse the order with `-r`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` works on lines, not words.

For the example you've shown us, you're sorting a single line of text.  For example:

```
$ echo 2.text 11.text 3.text | sort -n
2.text 11.text 3.text
```

But that's inconsistent with the output you've shown us, so I can't be sure just what you're doing, or what you're trying to do.

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$ echo 2.text 11.text 3.text | fmt -1
2.text
11.text
3.text
$ echo 2.text 11.text 3.text | fmt -1 | sort -n
2.text
3.text
11.text
```

And do you need to re-assemble the lines into a single line?  Piping the output through `fmt -999` will do that, but that's a bit ugly (GNU coreutils `fmt` limits the width to 2500).

Comment: I think `paste -s` should reconstruct the single line afterwards

Comment: @Daenyth: Yes, that should work.  Add `-d ' '` to delimit with spaces rather than tabs.

Answer (score 1):

convert white spaces in linebreaks with `tr`; and now `sort`; and convert linebreaks back to white spaces

> echo "2.test 1.test 9.test" | tr " " "\n" | sort | tr "\n" " "

ps. saw this somewhere in a forum